# Classify literal and expression in negative numbers

Tags: python-3.x

For example a negative number -1

I think this is an expression with a unary operator '-' and a numeric literal '1'.
But I cannot be sure.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community -Thank you

Comment: A minus sign before a number is the representation of a negative number, represented in binary as a signed bit. In arithmetic, it can be used in two contexts - as a unary operator, or as a binary operator. So, 3 separate contexts, not to be confused with one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the Python grammar, `-1` is not a literal. It's a unary negation applied to a literal `1`. As well as being deducible from the lexical rules of Python, this is also explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#numeric-literals) of Python's lexical structure:

> Note that numeric literals do not include a sign; a phrase like `-1` is actually an expression composed of the unary operator ‘`-`‘ and the literal `1`.

Most of the time, though, people will refer to `-1` as a literal, much the same way they refer to `[1, 2, 3]` as a "list literal" even though the grammar calls that a "list display".

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could say, "a little of this and a little of that", check this expressions in a python's prompt:

```
   2-3
=> -1

   --1
=> 1

   -1
=> -1

   ---1
=> -1

   ----1
=> 1

-(5+10)
=> -15
```

***It depends on the context*** though, look at this example:

```
   -1
=> -1
```

here, `-` denotes the negative of the `int` , but look at this one:

```
   2-3
=> -1
```

here is unary operation:

```
  -(5+10)
=> -15
```

here, the `-` denotes the `sub` function, and the others... just cancelations.

Comment: It obvious that in 2-3 and --1, minus sign is an operator. But should I consider minus sign in -1 as a part of the integer or an expression?

Comment: @ZaynJarvis if the expression is `-1` you must consider part of the expression, yes. otherwise is an operator